# Not able to execute Kafka Producer Code in Loadrunner

Tags: java, apache-kafka, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am trying to send a message to Kafka cluster through a java program in Loadrunner 12.50 using Java Vuser protocol.
The code looks like:

```js
import lrapi.lr;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.*;

public class Actions
{
  
 
    public int init() throws Throwable {
        return 0;
    }

  public int action() throws Throwable {
      String topicName = "TopicName";
      String value = "PTTest1";

      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("bootstrap.servers", "AAA-abcde-001:9092");
      props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");         
      props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

     Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer <String,String>(props);

      ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String,String>(topicName,value);
      producer.send(record);           
      producer.close();
      return 0;
    }//end of action
 
  public int end() throws Throwable {
        return 0;
    }

  }
```

Though it does not give any compilation errors in Vugen, it fails during run time with below error:

**Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) at DummyClassLoader.loadClass(DummyClassLoader.java:15) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at ScriptFactory.getScriptObject(ScriptFactory.java:50) Error: Can't create script object. Error: Exception was raised when calling abort-cleanup function in extension java_int.dll: System Exceptions: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION**

I have used kafka-clients-0.9.0.0.jar(kafka-clients-0.10.0.0. jar as well), java-util-1.3.1.jar and jre6\lib\rt.jar in runtime classpath and have JDK 1.6 for Vugen compatibility.

I have tried setting up environment and system variables but the error still persists. Can you please point me in the right direction to resolve this error.

Comment: 32 or 64 bit java?  It makes a difference

Comment: classpath referring to 32 bit